# Question about the diffrence between "something" and "anything" in the context below

Tags: grammar

> Do you have something to eat?
>
> Do you have anything to eat?

What is the difference in their meaning? Even slight difference.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking the person if they can give *you* something/anything   to eat, there is very little difference.  Both are vague requests.

But even if it were specific:

- Do you have any SPAM?
- Do you have some SPAM?

  it would not make a difference.

However, this might not be asking someone for food.  You might be asking whether *they* have something/anything *for them to eat.*

If you ask if they have *something* to eat, it usually refers to the present moment; e.g. something to eat for lunch.

If you ask whether they have *anything* to eat, you might be wondering whether their cupboards are completely bare, so that they have nothing to eat—neither now nor later.

Answer (score 0):

I think...

"something" refers to a noun which is finite. Said that, when we have fewer possibilities or limited things to select from, we use 'something'.

On the other hand, "anything" refers to a noun which is infinite and we have bigger number or great possibilities to choose from. It may not be selective and it is 'larger than' something.

> Do you have something to eat?

You are hungry and probably asking for food (may be of your choice)

But...

> Do you have anything to eat?

Here, you are **famished**, you are ready to eat anything available.

In this context (and so in any), 'anything' over 'something' simply intensifies whatever you are talking about.

Compare...

> I'll do something for you -selective, limited

over...

> I'll do anything for you -aggressive, possessive, intensified, unlimited.