# Which to use, somewhere and anywhere?

Tags: word-choice, some-vs-any

A) Are you planning to go somewhere on vacation?

B) Are you planning to go anywhere on vacation?

Is there any difference between the two?

Comment: The "planning" and "on vacation" don't affect the basic usage, which is more straightforwardly featured in *Do you want to go **somewhere / anywhere**?, Can I get you **something / anything**? Are you with **someone / anyone**?* Offhand I can't think of any context where the ***some / any*** choice would affect the meaning of any of *my* examples, but there are many other contexts where you can *only* use one or the other. And although both forms are valid with, say, *He will eat **any** food* and *He will eat **some** food*, there's definitely a significant difference in meaning with those.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Am I missing something vs anything](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/265076/). Also [Question about the diffrence between "something" and "anything" in the context below](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/58155/) and ["Some" and "Any"; countables and uncountable](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/38030/), among others.

Comment: Thank you for answering and I'm sorry for my misinterpretation last time.